# WPF - Filtering a DataCollection with an autocompletebox

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, filter, autocompletebox

I have a view and ViewModel that are working perfectly. I have recently added an AutocompleteBox (found in the WPF Toolkit) which allows users to quickly look up an item.

My view is as such:

- An ItemsControl containing my CollectionViewSource named People. Generating perfectly
- An AutocompleteBox where the dropdown shows only the items containing the values the user is typing in the AutocompleteBox. Works well. If I type John, all of the people in my CollectionViewSource named People with the word John in the name appear in the dropdown.

My issue is: how do I filter my ItemsControl when the user selects the item he wishes to see from the Dropdown?

My code so far in XAML to bind the data:

```
<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox Height="25" Width="400"
                                     Foreground="AliceBlue"
                                     ItemsSource="{Binding People.View}"
                                     ValueMemberPath="Name"
                                     Text="{Binding Name}"
                                     IsTextCompletionEnabled="True"
                                     FilterMode="Contains"
                                     Background="#303030">
                <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Width="360" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="SemiBold" Foreground="#25A0DA"
                                           FontSize="14" Width="300"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}" FontWeight="Normal" Foreground="White"
                                           FontSize="10" Width="300"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
            </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>

<ItemsControl x:Name="tStack" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding People.View}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      BorderThickness="0.5">
</ItemsControl>
```

The itemsControl is styled and the format of the items inside it are also templated/styled but far too long and unconstructive to post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `Name` property setter in your viewmodel to which `toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.Text` is bound, you will have to filter the ObservableCollection backing your `Collectionview` i,e `ItemsSource` of your `ItemsControl`.

If you have your Collectionsource with you then you can have filter applied to it like below:

```
ICollectionView _peopleView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(peoples);
_peopleView .Filter = PeopleFilter

private bool PeopleFilter(object item)
{
    People people= item as People;
    return people.Name.Contains( _filterString ); //Here filter string will be your Name prperty value
}
```

From Setter of name property you will hav to call `_peopleView .Refresh()`; to apply the filter

Thanks

Comment: I think I understand the concept of your code but what exactly do I put in the place of _filterString ? Do I have to create a public string with get; set; attributes?

Comment: you will put the value of 'Name' that user has selected